# Automatically detaching choice renderer in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I often find myself in a situation where I'm creating a choice to select a value for a property on a simple object, e.g.

```
public class Customer {
    private Integer customerSiteId;
}

public class CustomerSite {
    private Integer id;
}
```

I have a list of the actual object, e.g. `CustomerSite` class, but my choice is based on the integer, i.e. the choices are integers which correspond to site IDs.

I want to make an implementation of `IChoiceRenderer` for such use cases, which internally creates a separate model for efficiency

```
public class IdSelectionRenderer<T, S> implements IChoiceRenderer<T> {

    IModel<Map<T, S>> displayMap;

    public IdSelectionRenderer(IModel<Collection<S>> displays, Function<S, T> idObtainer) {

        displayMap = new LoadableDetachableModel<Map<T, S>>() {
            @Override
            protected Map<T, S> load() {
                return displays
                        .getObject()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(idObtainer, Function.identity()));
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public Object getDisplayValue(T object) {
        return displayMap.getObject().get(object);
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdValue(T object, int index) {
        return object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject(String id, IModel<? extends List<? extends T>> choices) {
        return Optional
                .ofNullable(choices.getObject())
                .get()
                .stream()
                .filter(choice -> choice.toString().equals(id))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

}
```

Is there a way to have wicket automatically detach such internal models while keeping them strictly inside the renderer?

Comment: models connected to components have full life cycle, with detaching. If not connected, haven't. I'm not sure understand You ...

Comment: In components you can hook any internal models to you declared to detach by overriding `detach()`. I was wondering if its possible to hook up an internal model on a choice renderer to somehow be detached as well. Behaviors have their own `detach()` and so so I was curious if maybe choice renderers could possibly have a similar option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Wicket does not detach choice renderers, so there is no way to hook your model. You will have to do it "manually".

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: Wicket 8 fixes this problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-6347

Comment: It would be great if you could add some more details from the link you have shared...